# NSButton tinting image in drawRect

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I want to tint my button in drawRect, but cannot find the right setup to tint the image

**- the button is borderless, with a grayscale image, which i want to tint**

In my NSButton subclass :

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{

    if ([self.cell mouseDownFlags] == 0) {

        [[NSColor redColor] set];

    } else {

        [[NSColor blackColor] set];

    }

    NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositePlusDarker);

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setFill`:

```
[[NSColor redColor] setFill];
```

...